# How to use Pandas dataframe as global variable?

Tags: python, pandas, flask

I am running a flask application and using the variable `merged` in the `read_uploaded_file` function which is defined in the `data_prediction` function.

Now i understand it might be because i have not assigned the merged variable globally or locally in the function where it is being used. Can someone please suggest how can i use the dataframe `merged` here or a better way of implementation ?

Error:

```
count_by_prediction = merged.groupby('Prediction').count()[['Incident Number']].sort_values(by=['Incident Number'], ascending=False)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'merged' referenced before assignment
```

Code:

```
def data_prediction(filename):

    model_name = 'SVM.sav'
    SVM = pickle.load(open(model_name, 'rb'))

    df_prediction = pd.read_csv(filename,encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
    df_prediction = df_prediction.applymap(lambda x: x.strip() if isinstance(x, str) else x)

    df_prediction["Description"].fillna(" ", inplace = True) 
    df_prediction['Full description'] = df_prediction['Short Description'] + " " +  df_prediction['Description']
    X_predict = df_prediction['Full description']
    display(X_predict)

    documents_predict = []

    for sen in range(0, len(X_predict)):
        # Remove all the special characters
        document = re.sub(r'\W', ' ', str(X_predict[sen]))

        # remove all single characters
        document = re.sub(r'\s+[a-zA-Z]\s+', ' ', document)

        # Remove single characters from the start
        document = re.sub(r'\^[a-zA-Z]\s+', ' ', document) 

        # Substituting multiple spaces with single space
        document = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', document, flags=re.I)

        # Removing prefixed 'b'
        document = re.sub(r'^b\s+', '', document)

        # Converting to Lowercase
        document = document.lower()

        documents_predict.append(document)

    data_for_predict = pd.Series(documents_predict)
    predicted_svm_actual_data = SVM.predict(data_for_predict.values.astype('U'))
    output=pd.DataFrame(data={"Description":data_for_predict,"Prediction":predicted_svm_actual_data})
    merged = pd.merge(left=df_prediction, left_index=True,right=output, right_index=True,how='inner')
    columns = ['Description_x', 'Description_y']
    merged.drop(columns, inplace=True, axis=1)
    print('HHH')
    print(merged)



    #Provide the name of output file. it will contain the description and predicted output/category
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r"predicted_output.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
    merged.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
    writer.save()
    print(merged)
    return merged



@app.route('/read_file', methods=['GET'])
def read_uploaded_file():
    filename = secure_filename(request.args.get('filename'))
    product = request.args.get("product")

    try:
        if filename and allowed_file(filename):
            if(product=='itanywhere'):
                print('itanywhere is happening')
                merged = data_prediction(filename)                
    except IOError:
        pass
    send_from_directory(directory=UPLOAD_FOLDER, filename='predicted_output_new_2.xlsx')

    count_by_prediction = merged.groupby('Prediction').count()[['Incident Number']].sort_values(by=['Incident Number'],\
                                                                                                ascending=False)
    display(merged)
    plt.figure(figsize = (20,8))
    plt.xticks(rotation=90)
    #plt.tight_layout()
    sn.countplot('Prediction', data=merged)
    img = io.BytesIO()  # create the buffer
    plt.savefig(img, format='png',bbox_inches = "tight")  # save figure to the buffer
    img.seek(0)  # rewind your buffer
    plot_data = urllib.parse.quote(base64.b64encode(img.read()).decode()) # base64 encode & URL-escape
    return render_template('data.html',plot_url=plot_data,tables_summary=[count_by_prediction.to_html(classes='data')], titles_summary=count_by_prediction.columns.values,\
                           tables=[merged.to_html(classes='data')], titles=merged.columns.values)




if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare merged as a global variable outside any function and then use it using `global` keyword inside the functions. When you make any change to merged in `data_prediction` it will be reflected in `read_uploaded_file` also.

```
merged=pd.DataFrame()

def data_prediction(filename):

    model_name = 'SVM.sav'
    SVM = pickle.load(open(model_name, 'rb'))

    df_prediction = pd.read_csv(filename,encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
    df_prediction = df_prediction.applymap(lambda x: x.strip() if isinstance(x, str) else x)

    df_prediction["Description"].fillna(" ", inplace = True) 
    df_prediction['Full description'] = df_prediction['Short Description'] + " " +  df_prediction['Description']
    X_predict = df_prediction['Full description']
    display(X_predict)

    documents_predict = []

    for sen in range(0, len(X_predict)):
        # Remove all the special characters
        document = re.sub(r'\W', ' ', str(X_predict[sen]))

        # remove all single characters
        document = re.sub(r'\s+[a-zA-Z]\s+', ' ', document)

        # Remove single characters from the start
        document = re.sub(r'\^[a-zA-Z]\s+', ' ', document) 

        # Substituting multiple spaces with single space
        document = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', document, flags=re.I)

        # Removing prefixed 'b'
        document = re.sub(r'^b\s+', '', document)

        # Converting to Lowercase
        document = document.lower()

        documents_predict.append(document)

    data_for_predict = pd.Series(documents_predict)
    predicted_svm_actual_data = SVM.predict(data_for_predict.values.astype('U'))
    output=pd.DataFrame(data={"Description":data_for_predict,"Prediction":predicted_svm_actual_data})

    global merged
    merged = pd.merge(left=df_prediction, left_index=True,right=output, right_index=True,how='inner')
    columns = ['Description_x', 'Description_y']
    merged.drop(columns, inplace=True, axis=1)
    print('HHH')
    print(merged)



    #Provide the name of output file. it will contain the description and predicted output/category
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r"predicted_output.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
    merged.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
    writer.save()
    print(merged)
    return merged



@app.route('/read_file', methods=['GET'])
def read_uploaded_file():
    filename = secure_filename(request.args.get('filename'))
    product = request.args.get("product")

    global merged
    try:
        if filename and allowed_file(filename):
            if(product=='itanywhere'):
                print('itanywhere is happening')
                merged = data_prediction(filename)                
    except IOError:
        pass
    send_from_directory(directory=UPLOAD_FOLDER, filename='predicted_output_new_2.xlsx')

    count_by_prediction = merged.groupby('Prediction').count()[['Incident Number']].sort_values(by=['Incident Number'],\
                                                                                                ascending=False)
    display(merged)
    plt.figure(figsize = (20,8))
    plt.xticks(rotation=90)
    #plt.tight_layout()
    sn.countplot('Prediction', data=merged)
    img = io.BytesIO()  # create the buffer
    plt.savefig(img, format='png',bbox_inches = "tight")  # save figure to the buffer
    img.seek(0)  # rewind your buffer
    plot_data = urllib.parse.quote(base64.b64encode(img.read()).decode()) # base64 encode & URL-escape
    return render_template('data.html',plot_url=plot_data,tables_summary=[count_by_prediction.to_html(classes='data')], titles_summary=count_by_prediction.columns.values,\
                           tables=[merged.to_html(classes='data')], titles=merged.columns.values)




if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```